# Android SSO login popup window

Tags: android, url, popup, single-sign-on

I need to program an Android application that integrates with a web-based system that has SSO (Single Sign On) authentication. The system will pop up a web page that prompts for the  username and password, if the login is successful then it sets a (memory based) cookie with an encrypted session ID, then the popup window will "kill" itself with a javascript window.close() function call. All standard stuff really, I have written Excel VBA applications on Windows that work perfectly well with this system - the user wants to log in, the SSO server will pop up an IE window,  the user provides their credentials and the window disappears, from then on integration from Excel to the remote system works because there is a session cookie created.

I tried to do the same with an Android app. I called the SSO login page with a WebView call, it displayed perfectly well and I logged in, expecting the login popup page to disappear and my Android application to continue. However, my problem is that in Android, a javascript call to windows.close() is effectively ignored, all it does is blank the screen and leave it showing. Thats fine, I dont care if the window still exists, as long as my cookie is created, and the user can easily navigate back to my app.
So here is my question:

How can I pop up a URL, get the user to log in to the SSO, then *easily* get the user back to my application.

I have done a lot of reading and experimentation but have reached a brick wall.

Thanks,

Steve

Answer (score 0):

May be you already know it, but by default, JavaScript is turned off in WebView widgets. If you want to enable JavaScript, call `getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true)` on the `WebView` instance to enable javascript.
I've written twitter client and they use OAuth for authentication. After login they simply redirect browser to the page you provide and can register activity for this action.
In your case if they just close the window, may be previous activity from the stack will be shown.

Comment: Yes, thanks for the tip on enabling Javascript, I neglected to say in my original post that I have already done that. My problem is that I want the user to return to my app after logging in, not go to a web page. I am not sure how to do that!

Comment: With WebView you can catch redirection (which will happen after log in) and call your activity to show what you want

Comment: P.S. Using method setWebViewClient(), you set up WebViewClient object with implemented method onLoadResource() and you can call your activity from there

Comment: I am still struggling, I can see how the WebViewClient and the WebChromeClient are supposed to work but I still cannot get a simple example working for my situation. I have started a WebView which is a login page with username/password fields and a login button. When the user clicks the login button, I want to detect that activity and return to my application. I have tried overriding various WebView Client and WebChromeClient methods to do this, but either nothing happens (the web page just goes blank) or the WebView does not even pop up. Why is this so difficult?

Comment: Please update your question with your code. I remember that I used setWebViewClient() with one of the methods and it worked. Have you tried to override all methods and put a Toast message inside?

Comment: `mWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);
 mWebView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
 mWebView.setWebChromeClient(new MyWebChromeClient());
//  mWebView.setWebViewClient(new MyWebViewClient());

  mWebView.loadUrl(URL);
 }
final class MyWebChromeClient extends WebChromeClient {
 @Override
 public void onCloseWindow(WebView window) {
 super.onCloseWindow(window);
 Toast.makeText(scanapps.this,"Detected chrome", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}
}
`

Comment: A bit hard to see, but the WebViewClient class looks like this:` final class MyWebViewClient extends WebViewClient {
  @Override
  public void onLoadResource(WebView view, String url )
  {Toast.makeText(scanapps.this,"Detected WebViewClient", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
  super.onLoadResource(view, url);}
 }
 
`

Comment: First: delete ChromeClient, you don't need it. Second: delete calling super in your onLoadResource(). Third: try to put a logging message inside this method, may be Toast is not displayed or something. I trust logs only :)

Comment: This is very frustrating, whenever I add the WebViewClient the WebView does not show! (Even if there are no subclasses in my WebViewClient class). I know its running in the background because I can see the hits on my webserver, and when I re-run the application I can briefly see the web page as the app is destroyed and a new version of the app is reloaded. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: OK, I have a solution, thanks for your help. As is usual in these cases, I was looking in the wrong place. I had a problem with my main.xml where a TextView was covering the WebView. Once I fixed that I can see the WebView fine.